# Groovy Sql get difference datetime compare with mysql cli

Tags: mysql, groovy

In mysql cli, i get following result:

```
mysql> select * from words limit 1;
+----+------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name | full               | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 30 | prpr | a full explanation | 2016-09-20 12:59:07 | 2016-09-20 12:59:07 |
+----+------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

the "created_at" is 2016-09-20 12:59:07

but when i

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    def c = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ro_test", "root", "root")
    println c.rows("select * from words")[0]['created_at']
}
```

the output is

```
2016-09-21 05:30:58.0
```

I hope groovy code output is same with mysql cli, how to do that?

Comment: What timezone are you in? Does it have something to do with your local time offset from UTC?

Answer (score 0):

These two dates probably refer to (roughly) the same instant in time. Given that the dates are 5.5 hours apart, my guess is that the MySQL CLI is showing the date in the UTC timezone, whereas the Groovy code is showing the date in the UTC+05:30 (Indian) time zone.

In other words

`2016-09-20 12:59:07 + 5.5 hours ≈ 2016-09-21 05:30:58.0`

Comment: So is there way to make groovy sql result same with mysql cli, for ex, how to override #rows method

Comment: The groovy date *is* already the same as the MySQL CLI, they're just being formatted differently when you display them. Similarly, the US date `09/30/2001' refers to the same day as this ISO date `2001-09-30`

Answer (score 0):

When I force specific timezone, it work

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    def c = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ro_test", "root", "root")
    def tz = TimeZone.default
    def cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai"))
    c.query("select * from words") { ResultSetImpl rs ->
        while (rs.next()) {
            println rs.getTimestamp(4, cal)
        }
    }
}
```

I think the best way is rewrite Groovy.sql.Sql#rows with above code, the full implementation is here:

```
List<LinkedHashMap> e2(String stmt) {
    def cal = Calendar.getInstance(Time.timezone)
    List<GroovyRowResult> rs = []
    c.query(stmt) { ResultSetImpl rs2 ->
        def md = rs2.metaData
        int cc = md.columnCount
        while (rs2.next()) {
            def attrs = [:]
            for (int i = 1; i <= cc; i++) {
                def key = md.getColumnLabel(i)
                def t = md.getColumnType(i)
                def v
                if (t == Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                    v = rs2.getTimestamp(i, cal)
                } else {
                    v = rs2.getObject(i)
                }
                attrs[key] = v
            }
            rs.add(attrs)
        }
    }
    rs
}
```